# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'version' of undefined at file

Tags: javascript, cordova

For saving canvas image to gallery i tried by creating plugin along with below piece of  javascript code in phonegap, but after button click i got "`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'version' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:18"`
     for the code

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="SavePhotoPlugin.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" /> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

 function onDeviceReady() {
        var element = document.getElementById('myCanvas');

    }
    function share() {      

        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        window.savephotoplugin(canvas,"image/png",device.version,function(val){ 
          //returns you the saved path in val   
                alert("Photo Saved: " + val);   
        });
    }
</script>
    </head>
     <body>

       <div >

     <IMG SRC="loadin.png" ALT="some text" WIDTH=100 HEIGHT=100>
     <button class="button" id="myCanvas" onclick="share()">SAVE </button>
      </div>
```

i tried with cordova 2.2, 2.9 for all the version the remains the same, tested on 2.3 version device. is this problem with the cordova version of device, or some other issue, please anybody point out mistake.

Comment: you first need to check whether the device is ready or not using the deviceready listener. document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false); here onDeviceReady is a callback function.

Comment: please see my edited question, still i'm getting the same error @SHANK

Comment: Try to alert the device object on the device ready function.

Answer (score 5):

Latest versions of jQuery no longer support browser detection. Most recommend feature detection over browser detection these days.

You need to revert to jQuery libraries previous to 1.9, use the jQuery migrate plugin, or modify your JavaScript code referencing the browser version to something different like Modernizr.

Answer (score 0):

Like already mentioned in the comment, you should run your code that accesses the `device` only after the [deviceready](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready) event has fired.

Another problem is that you define a `device` variable inside your `share()` function. This will overwrite the cordova device object even if you run this after deviceready. So remove the line `var device`.

Comment: tried with deviceready event also and removed var device, but still error remains the same @ville